# change date output in file

Tags: shell-script

I am looking to convert this kind of entry in a txt file 26/04/2008 to April 2008

Note : this is not using the date command , these are date entries in a file

Can I do this with sed ?

This is part of a one liner script using pipe etc

Comment: What does the text file look like?

Comment: You already have [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233981/89144)

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't work with (just) `sed` because you're having to parse the date as part of the process.

You can do it with a combination of the `date` command, or personally I'd go with `perl` - you can use it a lot like `sed` but it also has the `Time::Piece` module that does date parsing too.

Runnable example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece; 

while ( <DATA> ) {
   chomp; 
   print Time::Piece->strptime($_, "%d/%m/%Y")->strftime("%B %Y"),"\n";
}

__DATA__
26/04/2008
26/05/2008
26/07/2009
```

Which you can 'one liner' for use in pipes (or you can specify files to process as arguments at the end):

```
perl -MTime::Piece -nle 'print Time::Piece->strptime($_, "%d/%m/%Y")->strftime("%B %Y");'
```

Note - both these assumes that dates are just one per line. It's not particularly difficult to extract it as a substring if desired though, and effectively 'sed' it as a substring pattern.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece; 

while ( <DATA> ) {
   s|(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})|Time::Piece->strptime($1, "%d/%m/%Y")->strftime("%B %Y")|e;
   print;
}

__DATA__
26/04/2008 and some text here 
a line like this with a date of 26/05/2008 
26/07/2009 and some more here maybe
```

Will turn that into:

```
April 2008 and some text here 
a line like this with a date of May 2008 
July 2009 and some more here maybe
```

Again, would one-liner-ify as:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -pe 's|(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})|Time::Piece->strptime($1, "%d/%m/%Y")->strftime("%B %Y")|e;'
```

Comment: i need to use bash with this im afraid - any way of doing it with bash ?

Comment: You've already said you want to use `sed` - which isn't `bash`. `perl` is installed in almost all the places `sed` is. And `Time::Piece` is part of perl core. But the answer is "probably, but it'll be harder". `date` will let you convert the different string formats back and forth just like the above. Can you help me understand why you have that constraint? The inline commands I quoted should work on most modern Unix variants.

Comment: so no way of using bash ?

Comment: OK. But why can you not use `perl` in `sed`-mode?

Comment: In "pure" bash, without calling any of the other commands? Not sure. Probably not. You'll be looking at extracting the date string (which is easiest using something like`sed`) and then converting it (which is easiest using something like `date`).

Comment: In case it's not clear - I've written `perl` code to make it clear what's happening, but have condensed it down into a "one liner" that you could use exactly the same way as you would have used `sed`.